# JavaScript - How do I display a text, character by character

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to display a text taken from an array, character by character using JavaScript. I have managed to do it with one part of the array. I can't find a way of going to a newline and displaying the rest.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var notes = [
{scenario: 1, intro: "This is the introduction.", que: "What is the weight of ....?"},
{scenario: 2, intro: "This is the second scen.", que: "What is the second law of ...?"},
{scenario: 3, intro: "This is the third thing.", que: "What is the third law of ...?"},
];


function splTxt(txt) {
    // Split string into characters                                                                                                                                           
    t = txt.split('');
return t
}

function terminal(cl, i) {
// Create a div element and display message                                                                                                                               
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = cl;
container.appendChild(div);

// Take the first element of the array                                                                                                                                    
// and extract the intro string                                                                                                                                           
var txt = splTxt(notes[0].intro);
var i = 0;

// Display text, character by character                                                                                                                                   
var display = setInterval(function() {
    div.textContent += txt[i];
    if (i == (txt.length-1)) {
        clearInterval(display);
    }
    i += 1
}, 100);

}

terminal('blueTh', 0);
```

After it displayed `notes[0].intro`, I'd like it to go to a new line and display `notes[0].que`.

I have tried to do

```
var txt = splTxt(notes[0].intro + '<br />' +  notes[0].que);
```

But obviously, it just displays `<br />` and prints both messages on the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

- Insert `<br />` and  tell the browser to parse it as HTML.

  You can do this by using the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property instead of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

  This will allow you to use HTML things like `<br />`, but you will have to escape `&`, `<`, `>` when they are supposed to be plain text. Don't do this if you don't trust the text.

  ```js
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var notes = [
    {scenario: 1, intro: "This is the introduction.", que: "What is the weight of ....?"},
    {scenario: 2, intro: "This is the second scen.", que: "What is the second law of ...?"},
    {scenario: 3, intro: "This is the third thing.", que: "What is the third law of ...?"}
  ];
  function terminal(cl, i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = cl;
    container.appendChild(div);
    var txt = [notes[0].intro, notes[0].que].join('\n').split('');
    var i = 0;
    (function display() {
      if(i < txt.length) {
        div.innerHTML += txt[i].replace('\n', '<br />');
        ++i;
        setTimeout(display, 100);
      }
    })();
  }
  terminal('blueTh', 0);
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container"></div>
  ```
- Insert a newline character and tell the browser to display it properly.

  In HTML, whitespace characters collapse by default. You can change this behavior by setting the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property to `pre`, `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`. For example, `white-space: pre` preserves all whitespace and doesn't wrap text.

  ```js
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var notes = [
    {scenario: 1, intro: "This is the introduction.", que: "What is the weight of ....?"},
    {scenario: 2, intro: "This is the second scen.", que: "What is the second law of ...?"},
    {scenario: 3, intro: "This is the third thing.", que: "What is the third law of ...?"}
  ];
  function terminal(cl, i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = cl;
    container.appendChild(div);
    var txt = [notes[0].intro, notes[0].que].join('\n').split('');
    var i = 0;
    (function display() {
      if(i < txt.length) {
        div.textContent += txt[i];
        ++i;
        setTimeout(display, 100);
      }
    })();
  }
  terminal('blueTh', 0);
  ```

  ```css
  #container {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container"></div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you and excuse my ignorance but isn't the main obstacle the fact that splTxt splits the strings including the br tag which results in the fact that whatever the method, browser would still get <   b r  / > which would not be rendered, would it?

Comment: @Wasteland Yes, if you choose the `innerHTML` way you shouldn't split `<br />`. I have included an example.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
message = document.getElementById("fly").innerHTML; // $ = taking a new line
distance = 150; // pixel(s)
speed = 20; // milliseconds

var txt="",
 num=0,
 num4=0,
 flyofle="",
 flyofwi="",
 flyofto="",
 fly=document.getElementById("fly");


function stfly() {
 for(i=0;i != message.length;i++) {
  if(message.charAt(i) != "$")
   txt += "<span style='position:relative;visibility:hidden;' id='n"+i+"'>"+message.charAt(i)+"<\/span>";
  else
   txt += "<br>";
 }
 fly.innerHTML = txt;
 txt = "";
 flyofle = fly.offsetLeft;
 flyofwi = fly.offsetWidth;
 flyofto = fly.offsetTop;
 fly2b();
}

function fly2b() {
 if(num4 != message.length) {
  if(message.charAt(num4) != "$") {
   var then = document.getElementById("n" + num4);
   then.style.left = flyofle - then.offsetLeft + flyofwi / 2;
   then.style.top = flyofto - then.offsetTop + distance;
   fly3(then.id, parseInt(then.style.left), parseInt(then.style.left) / 5, parseInt(then.style.top), parseInt(then.style.top) / 5);
  }
  num4++;
  setTimeout("fly2b()", speed);
 }
}

function fly3(target,lef2,num2,top2,num3) {
 if((Math.floor(top2) != 0 && Math.floor(top2) != -1) || (Math.floor(lef2) != 0 && Math.floor(lef2) != -1)) {
  if(lef2 >= 0)
   lef2 -= num2;
  else
   lef2 += num2 * -1;
  if(Math.floor(lef2) != -1) {
   document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById(target).style.left = Math.floor(lef2);
  } else {
   document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById(target).style.left = Math.floor(lef2 + 1);
  }
  if(lef2 >= 0)
   top2 -= num3
  else
   top2 += num3 * -1;
  if(Math.floor(top2) != -1)
   document.getElementById(target).style.top = Math.floor(top2);
  else
   document.getElementById(target).style.top = Math.floor(top2 + 1);
  setTimeout("fly3('"+target+"',"+lef2+","+num2+","+top2+","+num3+")",25)
 }
}

stfly()
```

```html
<h4 id='fly'>This is dummy text for demo purpose</h4>
```